# How to void (soft delete) a record in database in a scalable fashion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Currently I have a `units` table with the following columns:

- `id`: PRIMARY Integer
- `name`: String
- `serial_id`: String
- . . .

As well as a `statuses` table. This Unit's data is sent to the server from our server. The `statuses` table has the following columns:

- `id`: PRIMARY Integer
- `internal_temp`: Float
- `battery_level`: Integer
- `unit_id`: FOREIGN KEY Integer
- `serial_id`: String
- ...

**Currently, I want to `void` out old units, so that way I can save new `units` with duplicate/same `serial_id`.** However, I still want to preserve the relationship that *voided* `units` and `statuses` have and maintain the relationship/data in an organized, scalable manner.

My first idea, was to simply add `is_void` to the `units` table and then do something like:

`Unit.where(serial_id: serial).find_by_is_void(false).statuses`

but, I am not sure if this will scale well. Currently, a `unit` makes nearly 2000 `status` entries per day.

I was thinking along the lines of creating a join table that can manage the relationship between the `unit` and `status` but I was unsure and wanted to seek some advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails 5 or lower, you could use the [paranoia gem](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) to implement the soft delete functionality. This gem requires us to add a column called `deleted_at` to the model which we want to soft_delete. It then uses a default scope to fetch only those records which *have not* been soft deleted. It provides various utility methods to easily fetch deleted records, *really* destroy records etc.

In case you are using Rails 6 or want to implement the soft deletion feature by yourself, here's what you would need to do:

1. Add a column called `deleted_at` to the model which you want to soft delete
2. Add a default scope in that model as `default_scope -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }`
3. You could then write utility methods to check if records are deleted or not, or scopes to fetch those records which are deleted as well. This API could be anything that you want
4. For scalability, you could even extract out all the common methods that you would want, associated with soft deleted models, into a concern which could simply be plugged in wherever required

As you can see, this implementation is extremely similar to what the paranoia gem provides out of the box. In case you're doing this for learning and have lots of time, I'd recommend building your own feature. If this is something that needs to be deployed soon in a professional project, I'd recommend using the gem since it may speed up the process.

This is a nice article which describes the paranoia gem and its features: [Rails Soft Delete with Paranoia gem](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/21/rails-soft-delete-with-paranoia-gem/)